# How to rerender specific row independently for picklist values

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, visualforce-component

I want to render picklist values based on each row when lookup is selected. There is a filter where it checks the recordtype of the lookup and based on it picklist value will be displayed.
The problem here is whenever the new row lookup is selected the other roles are also changed and the current values are shown in all the roles columns.

```
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Contact Roles" columns="1" id="idRoleSec">
            <apex:outputPanel id="PanelBtn">
                <apex:commandButton value="Select Existing Contact" action="{!MethodAddRole}"  rerender="idRoletbl" oncomplete="codeAddress();checkboxuse();"/> &nbsp;
                <apex:commandButton value="Create New Contact" action="{!MethodAddRole}" rerender="PanelBtn,idRoletbl" onclick="funOpenPop();" oncomplete="codeAddress();checkboxuse();"/><apex:image value="/s.gif" styleClass="helpIcon" title="Click on button to create new contact. Once new contact created, add new contact with the help of below magnifier icon"/>
            </apex:outputPanel> 
            <apex:outputPanel id="idWarn" style="color:Red;">Click on below magnifier icon to add newly created or existing contact.</apex:outputPanel>           
            <apex:pageblockSectionItem id="idSecR1" >
                <apex:outputText >Cust Survey Opt Out</apex:outputText>
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!objOppy.Cust_Survey_Opt_Out__c}" id="infchck" onchange="codeAddress(); onchangeofcheck(); return false;" styleClass="labelCol vflabelColTextWrap"/>
            </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listRoleWrap}" var="VarRole"  id="idRoletbl">
                <apex:column headerValue="Primary">
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!VarRole.objRole.Primary__c}" styleClass="Teststyle" onchange="return checkboxuse(this)" id="checkedone"
                                        disabled="{!If(VarRole.objRole.Contact__c == null,true,false)}"  />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Contact"> 
                    <apex:define name="requiredInputDiv">
                        <div class="requiredInput">
                            <apex:define name="requiredInputDiv"><div class="requiredBlock"/></apex:define>                                               
                            <apex:inputField value="{!VarRole.objRole.Contact__c}" onChange="populateEmail(this);" id="idCont"/>
                        </div>
                    </apex:define>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Email">
                    <apex:inputText value="{!VarRole.strNewEmail}" id="theTextInput" disabled="{!if(AND(VarRole.strOldEmail=='',VarRole.boolHasAccess),false,true)}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Role">             


                    <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!selectedrole}">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!rolesLst }"/>
                    </apex:selectList> <br/>

                    <!-- <apex:inputField value="{!VarRole.objRole.Role__c}"/> --> 
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Phase 1 Survey">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!VarRole.objRole.Phase_1_Survey__c}" styleClass="checkbox" id="check1"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Phase 2 Survey" rendered="{!strrecordtype .RecordType.Name != 'Voice'}">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!VarRole.objRole.Phase_2_Survey__c}" styleClass="checkbox" id="check2"/>
                </apex:column>  

            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Class

```
 public void populateEmailMethod()
{


  rolesLst =new List<SelectOption>();
         transient string strEmail = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('firstParam');
        contact c=[select id,name,accountid,account.Voice_Account_Type__c from contact where name=:strEmail limit 1];
        account a = [select id,name,Account_Type__c,Voice_Account_Type__c from account where id=:c.accountid];

        system.debug('a0--'+a);
        system.debug('c0--'+c);
        If(a.Voice_Account_Type__c!=null){
               if(a.Voice_Account_Type__c.contains('Partner')){
            accountvoice= true; 
            accountnonvoice = false;

        }else{
            accountnonvoice = true;
            accountvoice= false; 

        }
        }


        //   rolesLst.add(new SelectOption('','--None--'));

        if(accountvoice==true){
            rolesLst.add(new SelectOption('Economic','Economic'));
            rolesLst.add(new SelectOption('User','User'));
            rolesLst.add(new SelectOption('Technical','Technical'));
            rolesLst.add(new SelectOption('Coach','Coach'));

        }else if(accountnonvoice = true){
            rolesLst.add(new SelectOption('Voice Partner','Voice Partner'));
            rolesLst.add(new SelectOption('Voice Referral','Voice Referral'));
        }
}
```

ADD Contact Button

```
 public void MethodAddRole() 
    {
        Transient integer i = 0;
        for(OppyRoleWrapper objWrapRole:listRoleWrap)
        {
            if(objWrapRole.strNewEmail=='' && objWrapRole.objRole.contact__C==Null && objWrapRole.objRole.role__C==Null )
                i++;
        }
        if(i==0 || listRoleWrap.size()==0)
        {
            //US 388: Primary made true by default for first contact role
            if(listRoleWrap.isEmpty())
                listRoleWrap.add(new OppyRoleWrapper(intRoleCountLocal,new Contact_Role__c(Opportunity__c=objOppy.Id,Primary__c=true,Phase_1_Survey__c=!objoppy.Cust_Survey_Opt_Out__c,Phase_2_Survey__c=false),'',false));//US292:Changed phase 2 survey to default false
            else
                listRoleWrap.add(new OppyRoleWrapper(intRoleCountLocal,new Contact_Role__c(Opportunity__c=objOppy.Id,Primary__c=false,Phase_1_Survey__c=!objoppy.Cust_Survey_Opt_Out__c,Phase_2_Survey__c=false),'',false));//US292:Changed phase 2 survey to default false
            intRoleCountLocal++;
        }
    }
```

[image]

```
 public Class OppyRoleWrapper
{  
    public boolean accountvoice {get;set;}
    public boolean accountnonvoice {get;set;}
    public List<SelectOption> rolesLst {get;set;}
    public list<OppyRoleWrapper> listRoleWrap{get;set;}
    public id conid  {get;set;}
    public string str  {get;set;}

    public void populateEmailMethod(){

        str = String.valueOf(conid);
        system.debug('st--'+str);
        //rolesLst =new List<SelectOption>();
        // system.debug('test=='+listRoleWrap);
        transient map<Id, string> mapIdCon = new map<Id, string>();
        transient string strEmail = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('firstParam');
        contact c=[select id,name,accountid,account.Voice_Account_Type__c from contact where name=:strEmail limit 1];
        account a = [select id,name,Account_Type__c,Voice_Account_Type__c from account where id=:c.accountid];

        system.debug('a0--'+a);
        system.debug('c0--'+c);
        If(a.Voice_Account_Type__c!=null){
            if(a.Voice_Account_Type__c.contains('Partner')){
                accountvoice= true; 
                accountnonvoice = false;

            }else{
                accountnonvoice = true;
                accountvoice= false; 

            }
        }


        //   rolesLst.add(new SelectOption('','--None--'));

        if(accountvoice==true){
            rolesLst.add(new SelectOption('Economic','Economic'));
            rolesLst.add(new SelectOption('User','User'));
            rolesLst.add(new SelectOption('Technical','Technical'));
            rolesLst.add(new SelectOption('Coach','Coach'));

        }else if(accountnonvoice = true){
            rolesLst.add(new SelectOption('Voice Partner','Voice Partner'));
            rolesLst.add(new SelectOption('Voice Referral','Voice Referral'));
        }   

        transient map<Id, boolean> mapIsContactAccess = new map<Id, boolean>();
        transient set<Id> setRecordId = new set<Id>();
        if(strEmail!=Null && strEmail!='')
        {
            for(Contact objCont: [select id, email from contact where name!= '' and name!=Null and name=:strEmail])
            {
                mapIdCon.put(objCont.Id, objCont.email);
                setRecordId.add(objCont.Id);
            }
            if(setRecordId.size()>0)
            {
                for(UserRecordAccess objUserAccess : [SELECT HasEditAccess, RecordId  FROM UserRecordAccess WHERE RecordId In : setRecordId AND UserId =: UserInfo.getUserId() ])
                {
                    mapIsContactAccess.put(objUserAccess.RecordId, objUserAccess.HasEditAccess);
                }
            }
        }
        for(OppyRoleWrapper objWrap :listRoleWrap)
        {
            if(objWrap.objRole.Contact__c!=Null)
            {
                if(mapIdCon.containsKey(objWrap.objRole.Contact__c))
                {
                    objWrap.strNewEmail = mapIdCon.get(objWrap.objRole.Contact__c);
                    objWrap.stroldEmail = objWrap.strNewEmail;
                }
                objWrap.boolHasAccess =mapIsContactAccess.get(objWrap.objRole.Contact__c);
            }
        }
    }




    public SelectOption[] getRoleOptions() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption> ();
        options.add(new SelectOption('Economic','Economic'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('User','User'));

        return options;
    }


    public Integer intCount{get; set;}
    public Contact_Role__c objRole{get; set;}
    public string strOldEmail{get; set;}
    public string strNewEmail{get; set;}
    public boolean boolHasAccess{get; set;}
    /*Constructor to set all the fields*/
    public OppyRoleWrapper(Integer intCount, Contact_Role__c objRole, string strEmail, boolean boolHasAccess)
    {

        this.intCount = intCount; 
        this.objRole = objRole;
        strOldEmail=strEmail;
        strNewEmail=strEmail;
        this.boolHasAccess = boolHasAccess;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your select options need to be set per-row. As written now, each list refers to the same variable, so the output will be same for each row. Similarly, selecting a value will set all rows to the same value, because there's only one variable. Each row needs its own dedicated variable to write to. In other words, you need to use values from the existing wrapper class. Below are the minimum changes to look for.

---

```
public class OppyRoleWrapper {
  public SelectOption[] getRoleOptions() {
    // ... calculate the correct options
    return options;
  }
  // more code not displayed //
}
```

---

```
<apex:selectList size="1" value="{!VarRole.objRole.Role__c}">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!VarRole.roleOptions}"/>
</apex:selectList> <br/>
```

---

You have a few subtle bugs and missed optimizations as well.

---

```
if(listRoleWrap.isEmpty())
    listRoleWrap.add(new OppyRoleWrapper(intRoleCountLocal,new Contact_Role__c(Opportunity__c=objOppy.Id,Primary__c=true,Phase_1_Survey__c=!objoppy.Cust_Survey_Opt_Out__c,Phase_2_Survey__c=false),'',false));//US292:Changed phase 2 survey to default false
else
    listRoleWrap.add(new OppyRoleWrapper(intRoleCountLocal,new Contact_Role__c(Opportunity__c=objOppy.Id,Primary__c=false,Phase_1_Survey__c=!objoppy.Cust_Survey_Opt_Out__c,Phase_2_Survey__c=false),'',false));//US292:Changed phase 2 survey to default false
```

Can be changed to:

```
listRoleWrap.add(
  new OppyRoleWrapper(
    intRoleCountLocal,
    new Contact_Role__c(
      Opportunity__c=objOppy.Id,
        //US 388: Primary made true by default for first contact role
      Primary__c=listRoleWrap.isEmpty(),
      Phase_1_Survey__c=!objoppy.Cust_Survey_Opt_Out__c,
      Phase_2_Survey__c=false
    ),'',false));//US292:Changed phase 2 survey to default false
```

---

Watch out when comparing values, **especially** Boolean values. If you accidentally type `=` instead of `==`, this results in the value always being true (`=` is assignment, `==` is comparison).

---

If your code were later expanded, this code could cause problems, because this condition is always true.

```
}else if(accountnonvoice = true){
```

Avoid doing this. Always use Boolean values directly as Boolean values. Simply doing this will prevent this incredibly common mistake.

```
}else if(accountnonvoice) {
```

---

There's other things you can fix, too, but these are the major problems you'll want to address.

Comment: Brain, 
I need to get the values in this variable, I dont want to use inputfield. 
Assume if the input field has 1,2,3,4,5,6 and for few conditions i want to show 1,2,3,4 and others 5,6  so i cannot do this in input field. so i have written a custom picklist value
  `<apex:selectList size="1" value="{!selectedrole}">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!rolesLst }"/>
                    </apex:selectList> <br/>`

Comment: @Arvind Yes, as I explained, you need to show the options per row. You can't put two different values into the same variable at the same time.

Comment: Just another question brain, So based on the lookup value change i am querying from account and i am checking a boolean, will the logic remains same? 
Or i have to implement it in wrapper. If yes how will i get the value in wrapper?

Comment: @Arvind You'd do that in the wrapper so you can determine how to build the picklist. Since you are using a query, you might want to change the logic in this answer to cache the result that you found so you don't get a too-many-soql error.

Comment: select is working now but needed to change the values based on boolean check.. any snippets I am lost completely on how to invoke wrapper class based on the lookup change. This last help will solve my problems

Comment: `If(a.Voice_Account_Type__c!=null){
               if(a.Voice_Account_Type__c.contains('Partner')){
            accountvoice= true; 
            accountnonvoice = false;

        }else{
            accountnonvoice = true;
            accountvoice= false; 

        }
        }

        if(accountvoice==true){
 rolesLst.add(new SelectOption('Coach','Coach'));
        }else if(accountnonvoice = true){
             rolesLst.add(new SelectOption('Voice Referral','Voice Referral'));
        }`

Comment: @Arvind `<apex:inputField ...><apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!VarRole.populateEmail}" /></apex:inputField>` and move the populateEmail method in to the wrapper class, too.

Comment: `<apex:inputField  value="{!VarRole.objRole.Contact__c}"  id="idCont">
                                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange"   action="{!VarRole.populateEmailMethod}" />
                                    <apex:param id="conid" name="conid" value="{!VarRole.objRole.Contact__c}" assignTo="{!VarRole.conid}"/>
                                    
                                </apex:inputField>`


I am not able to get the contact id in controller. I used param aswell but unable to fetch it

Comment: I have updated my question aswell on wrapper class.
I know i am worng brain correct me pls. Because in the query i am getting list has no row exception.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88545/discussion-between-arvind-and-sfdcfox).