# How to call one method after another in wrapper class?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, visualforce-component

I Have a lookup based on that value selected i have to query and get the select options. I am trying to call the wrapper class but its throwing me null pointer error.guide me where i am going wrong.

```
 public Class OppyRoleWrapper
    {  
        public boolean accountvoice {get;set;}
        public boolean accountnonvoice {get;set;}
        public List<SelectOption> rolesLst {get;set;}
        public list<OppyRoleWrapper> listRoleWrap{get;set;}

 public void populateEmailMethod(){
            rolesLst = new  List<SelectOption>();
            transient map<Id, string> mapIdCon = new map<Id, string>();
            // transient string strEmail = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('firstParam');
            system.debug('listRoleWrap='+listRoleWrap);

            contact c=[select id,name,accountid,account.Voice_Account_Type__c from contact where id=:objrole.Contact__c limit 1];
            account a = [select id,name,Account_Type__c,Voice_Account_Type__c from account where id=:c.accountid];

            system.debug('a0--'+a);
            system.debug('c0--'+c);
            If(a.Voice_Account_Type__c!=null){
                if(a.Voice_Account_Type__c.contains('Partner')){
                    this.accountvoice= true; 
                    this.accountnonvoice = false;

                }else{
                    this.accountnonvoice = true;
                    this.accountvoice= false; 

                }
            }



 system.debug('listRoleWrap=='+listRoleWrap);
        for(OppyRoleWrapper objWrap :listRoleWrap)
        {
            if(objWrap.objRole.Contact__c!=Null)
            {
                if(mapIdCon.containsKey(objWrap.objRole.Contact__c))
                {
                    objWrap.strNewEmail = mapIdCon.get(objWrap.objRole.Contact__c);
                    objWrap.stroldEmail = objWrap.strNewEmail;
                }
                objWrap.boolHasAccess =mapIsContactAccess.get(objWrap.objRole.Contact__c);
            }
        }
    }

            // And more more custom logic 
   }

 public SelectOption[] getRoleOptions() {

            List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption> ();


            if(accountvoice==true){
                system.debug('-- loo check');
                options.add(new SelectOption('Economic','Economic'));
                options.add(new SelectOption('User','User'));
                options.add(new SelectOption('Technical','Technical'));
                options.add(new SelectOption('Coach','Coach'));

            }else if(accountnonvoice==false){
                options.add(new SelectOption('Voice Partner','Voice Partner'));
                options.add(new SelectOption('Voice Referral','Voice Referral'));
            }   


            return options;
        }


}
```

VF

```
  <apex:column headerValue="Contact"> 
                        <apex:define name="requiredInputDiv">
                            <div class="requiredInput">
                                <apex:define name="requiredInputDiv"><div class="requiredBlock"/></apex:define>                                               
                                <apex:inputField value="{!VarRole.objRole.Contact__c}"  id="idCont">
                                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange"   action="{!VarRole.populateEmailMethod}" />
                                    <apex:param id="conid" name="conid" value="{!VarRole.objRole.Contact__c}" assignTo="{!VarRole.conid}"/>

                                </apex:inputField>
                            </div>
                        </apex:define>
                    </apex:column>
   <apex:selectList size="1"  value="{!VarRole.objRole.Role__c}">
                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!VarRole.roleOptions}"/>
                            </apex:selectList> <br/>
```

My Populate method contains the boolean check, and from that method i need to call the getRolesoptions method based on the ONCHANGE of lookup value. 
Actionsupport did not work .or if my actionsupport is worng syntax.

Comment: which line is giving exception?

Comment: the one with  system.debug('listRoleWrap=='+listRoleWrap); 
Plus i am not getting any option values in page. Because getroleoptions is not invoked with apporiatite boolean.
To invoke that i need to get the boolean value from populateemailmethod

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mistaken about which like throws your `NullPointerException`.

```
System.debug('listRoleWrap=='+listRoleWrap);
```

is perfectly fine, whether or not `listRoleWrap` is `null`.  The following line, however,

```
    for(OppyRoleWrapper objWrap :listRoleWrap)
```

is not. If `listRoleWrap` is `null`, you'll get that exception here. Since your code nowhere initializes that variable, it appears that it'll always be `null`.

This class as posted is either incomplete or incorrect; it certainly won't compile in this form. It appears to me that you are trying to do way too much in a wrapper class. Wrapper classes are generally quite small and include only logic that's necessary to format or present the data that they encapsulate. Most of the code you're showing here *appears* to me to belong in your controller class.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/247290/how-to-rerender-specific-row-independently-for-picklist-values/
This is the question of why i have implemented wrapper for select option,
And have added a gif to my question aswell.

Comment: OK, that's fine, but you still need to initialize your variables and make sure that your code accesses the right data when needed. Because the code in your question is partial, it is hard to understand the full context. Your `populateEmailMethod` code *may* belong as part of the wrapper constructor, but it's really unclear, and I am very skeptical about executing two SOQL queries per wrapper object. That will get you into limits trouble fast.